# Extract h3's and a href's contents and save as dataframe in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to extract categories and items from [this link](https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/category/rql/) shown as in the images below and storing them into dataframe:

[image]

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:65.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/65.0"
headers = {"user-agent": USER_AGENT} # adding the user agent

url ='https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/category/rql'
resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
print(soup)
print(soup.text)
```

To loop all the sections:

```
lists = ['rql', 'scl', 'shucailei', 'guopinlei', 'mmdr', 'tiaoweipinl', 'yaoshiqita']
for l in lists:
    url ='https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/category/' + l
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, "html.parser")
    print(soup)
```

The category could be found in:

```
  <h3>
   ...
  </h3>
```

The items could be found in:

```
<li>
 <a href="https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/YaRou/" target="_blank" title="...">
 ...
</a>
```

How could I extract sections, categories, items, and save them as dataframe? Thanks.

Updated:

```
for el in soup.find_all('ul'):
    for i in el.find_all('a', href=True):
        print(list(i.children))
```

Comment: You need the `find()` and `find_all()` methods in Beautiful Soup, there are plenty of good examples in [the documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: I have found the first category and its items using `soup.find_all('h3')[0]` and `soup.find_all('ul')[2]`, how to get them all?

Comment: ’find_all()’ returns an iterable, you can loop through them and extract what you need item by item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all sections/categories/items into a dataframe, you can use this example:

```py
import requests
import pandas as ps
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/"
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
sections = [(a.text, a["href"]) for a in soup.select(".nav_wrap2 li a")]

all_data = []
for s_name, s in sections:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(
        requests.get(s, headers=headers).content, "html.parser"
    )

    for cat in soup.select(".category_sub"):
        print(cat.h3.text)
        for i in cat.select("li a"):
            print(i.text, i["href"])
            all_data.append([s_name, s, cat.h3.text, i.text, i["href"]])

    print("-" * 80)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    all_data,
    columns=["section", "section_link", "category", "item", "item_link"],
)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     section                                                section_link  category       item                                                   item_link
0         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         鸡肉                 https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/JiRou/
1         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         鸡翅                 https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/JiChi/
2         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         鸡蛋                 https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/JiDan/
3         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         牛肉                https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/NiuRou/
4         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         猪肉                https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/ZhuRou/
5         首页                       https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/     时令与热门         排骨                 https://www.meishichina.com/YuanLiao/PaiGu/

....
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, could pls provide a link so I'll try to buy a cup of coffee?